# How to set power setting to performance?

Tags: performance, battery

In Ubuntu 12.04 how do I set up the power settings to obtain maximum performance (opposed to max battery life)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this applet: [Jupiter](http://www.jupiterapplet.org/). It works fine for me.